# Is it possible to run ios simulator with Android studio in windows 10?

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

I am fresher in flutter. I opened my first project in flutter using android studio in windows 10 and run it in android emulator. It is working as expected. I want to run my app in ios emulator also. I searched in Google and YouTube a lot how to use an ios emulator with my Android studio in windows 10 but I couldn't success. Is it possible to have ios simulator or emulator in windows 10 to use with android studio or not? if it is not what should I do? Please anyone help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Short Answer: To run iOS simulator, you need to be on a Mac.